# SSE on GCP Cloud Run results in 503 error (works locally)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-run, remix.run, event-stream

I have a Remix app setup with Firebase hosting and Cloud Run to host the back end. I am not too familiar with the stack but can give more information if needed. For the firebase hosting and authorisation I used this as a guide: https://github.com/remix-run/examples/tree/main/firebase, however I switched to using cloud run instead of a firebase function for the server as I thought that could solve my issue.

For the event stream I have used 2 packages, https://github.com/dan-cooke/remix-sse/tree/main and https://github.com/sergiodxa/remix-utils, both of which do not work, when I run the app locally or use the ingress URL provided by cloud run the event stream works as expected however when trying to use the server from the front end this is where I encounter the 503 error after a 3 minute time out. [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gji3w.png) Because of this I believe the issue is caused by the routing of Fastly which can be seen in the response header, this provided an error 54113. [503](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi2yJ.png). Also these are the cloud run logs I get: [Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKPVl.png)